# absolute paths don't work for my leaflet custom icons

Tags: leaflet, javascript, icon, file-path

I've made an example leaflet project using a custom icon loading an image from the internet:

https://jsfiddle.net/dvdjsph/v30vL109/

As soon as I try to load something from my hard drive, however, the image won't load.  This is how I'm trying to load it.

```
var offerIcon = new OfferIcon(
    { iconUrl: "C:\image.jpg"});

L.marker([0, 0], {icon: offerIcon}).addTo(markers).bindPopup(name);
```

I know that JS fiddle won't load this -- it's on my hard drive.  I just put up the example to show that, minus that path, everything else is working fine.

Is there something I'm missing about paths with Leaflet?

EDIT:

At Matej's suggestion, I tried putting an icon in the same folder as my template and referencing it like so:

```
var offerIcon = new OfferIcon(
    { iconUrl: "image.jpg"});
```

Still not working.

Answer (score 3):

[URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) must have a *scheme* (also called *protocol*). In most cases, the scheme is `http://` or `https://`. If you do not specify a scheme, a browser will interpret that as a relative path, resolving it with the current scheme and hostname.

So if you have a webpage such as `http://localhost/test/foo.html`, and in that webpage is an image reference like `<img src='C:/users/me/image.jpg'>`, the full URL of the image will be resolved to `http://localhost/test/C:/users/me/image.jpg`.

If you want to use local files, remember to **use the [`file://` URL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)**, e.g.: `<img src='file:///C:/users/me/image.jpg'>`.

Comment: That's good to know.  Unfortunately, I'm still having my problem.  I logged what the URL ends up like: 
"icon name is: file:///C:\django\website\media\images\offer_icons\46\foxes.jpg"
Everything in the path is correct.

Comment: Use the "network" tab of your browser's developer console to see what's going on.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I came back to this and looked at the network tab.  what's strange is that, when I don't prepend the "file://" string, an error in loading is shown in the network tab.  When I do prepend it, there are no errors displayed, but it doesn't show any image being loaded from the url.